# Using custom C# class library in another project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I built a class library as a NuGet package to be used in another C# project.  When I built the class library, I followed a tutorial that suggested targeting .NET Standard 2.0.

I installed the package into the other project and it builds fine.  However, I've noticed that the output folder contains several other 'System.' dlls (ie. System.AppContext.dll).

In the past, when I've built a class library for C++, I did not get the dependent dlls copied to the output folder.  I had assumed that building a C# class library would act the same way.  For C++, those dependent dlls are resolved at runtime by the C++ redistributable dlls.  I thought the same would be true in that C# would resolve them through the installed framework.

So, I'm a bit confused as to why the extra dlls are present in the output folder.  Is it because I targeted .NET Standard 2.0?  Do I need to ship the extra dlls with my application?

Comment: You might find this reading informative: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/545

Comment: @Amy Thanks for that.  It looks like the information I need.

Comment: After targeting .Net 4.7.1, I found that I still have several 'System.' dlls in the release folder.  I think I need to target 4.7.2.